# Caching vs .querySelector

Tags: javascript

We're taught to cache selectors early on. Just do one lookup, they all say.

I wonder how this idea works with .querySelector.

Let's say I want to grab an element below one I've just clicked on. The js would be something like:

`this.querySelector('.toggle-this-content').classList.toggle('open')`

So I click on a button, and it toggles the content below it to open. Is this an expensive selection? I should probably do delegation properly, so I can say:

`toggleThisContent.classList.toggle('open')`

inside the function I'm using, but I'm wondering if that use of .querySelector is bad practice or A-Ok.

Comment: A simple single query inside `this` which is already known is not expensive compared to multiple queries in `document` to do multiple operations on one element. Question is not framed well to get much of an answer

Comment: "Is this an expensive selection?" --- Is $100 a lot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the word "expensive", and you use the word "bad practice". However, the two are not synonymous. Something could be expensive, yet good practice; or cheap, yet bad practice. Or, you could redefine the word "expensive", to mean not just something takes a lot of CPU cycles, but that it takes a lot of human cycles to write, read, debug, extend, and maintain.

Consider the following:

```
function foo(sel) { 
  if (document.querySelector(sel)) document.querySelector(sel).classList.add('bar');
}
```

As you suggest, most experienced programmers are likely to prefer

```
function foo(sel) { 
  let elt = document.querySelector(sel);
  if (elt) elt.classList.toggle('bar');
}
```

But actually the reason has nothing to do with performance, although this version probably performs marginally better (by which I mean, a few dozen microseconds faster, most likely). It is preferable because it is not repetitive. The single aspect of the programmer's intent to "retrieve the element selected by `sel`" is expressed exactly once, in a single `querySelector` call. The code is shorter, and less prone to typos. It seems more readable.

Let's take another case, where a specific `querySelector` is done in different parts of the code, so

```
function x1() {
  document.querySelector('.c1').classList.toggle('x1');
}

function x2() {
  document.querySelector('.c1').classList.toggle('x2');
}
```

In this case, arranging to do only a single `querySelector('.c1')` requires computing and holding the element somewhere where it is available to either of the two calls--just as a simple example:

```
let x = function() {
  let elt = document.querySelector('.c1');
  return { 
    x1: function() { elt.classList.toggle('x1'); },
    x2: function() { elt.classList.toggle('x2'); }
  };
}();

x.x1();
```

You've successfully reduced the number of calls to `querySelector` to one, which will save you a few dozen microseconds, but at the cost of somewhat more complicated code.

So in this case, all else being equal, if it were a matter of looking at the original code (the two separate function calls) and asking how important it was to refactor it into the second fragment (IIFE), the answer would be, "almost not at all".

Which is not to say that it would not be a good idea to refactor this at a higher level. You are engaging in the anti-pattern of binding your DOM manipulation code too closely to specific classes (or in other cases commonly seen, IDs). In this pattern, programmers use IDs and classes as a kind of variable name for referring to DOM elements, and everywhere they need to get the actual element, retrieve it over and over again from the huge global DOM namespace using `getElementById` or `getElementsByClassName` or `querySelector`. It is far better to use DOM elements stored in variables to refer to DOM elements, and restrict the mapping of those variables to specific elements via their ID or class to the smallest possible surface area in one part of your code. This is not a matter of performance, but rather one of good code structure. That way, for example, you could rename class `c1` in your HTML and have only one place in your code that would need to be changed. Of course, this would require arranging your code so that the variables are available where needed. But that is really no different than arranging your code to not use global variables--since `querySelector('.c1')` is a kind of global variable--which is something you should be doing anyway.

Comment: Thanks for this. Great answer. Your last paragraph brings up a thousand more questions though!   The main question is about: "the anti-pattern of binding your DOM manipulation code too closely to specific classes".   I'm not sure what the alternative pattern is. I want to do stuff to certain elements with classes/ids. How would I do that in a more organized manner?  Here's an example of how I do this stuff now.  Love to yget your thoughts. https://gist.github.com/saltcod/eed09ff717cdde13cad7